# How to generate the number using mathematica satisfying the recursion

Tags: differential-equations, recursion

I have the following recursion for 
\begin{align}
  (d^{3} -3d^{2}+2d)he_{g}(d) +(-2d^{3}+10d^{2}-18d+12)he_{g}(d-2)+(d^{3}-7d^{2}+16d-12)he_{g}(d-4)\\+(4d-8)he_{(g-1)}(d-2)+(6-2d)he_{(g-1)}(d-4)=0
 \end{align}
Also the initial condition I want to impose is $h_g(d)=0$ if $g<0$. Is there is anyway I can solve for $h_g (d)$? Looking for a nontrivial solution that is $h_g(d)\neq 0$

Comment: Looks like `Fold` and `FoldList` could be of help.

Comment: That's a package in mathematica?